# redirect in .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

One site just linked to my website with incorrect URL as:

```
http://www.datanumen.com/aor/%e2%80%9d
```

I find this and want to correct this by redirecting the URL to:

```
http://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair/
```

Therefore, I add the following line in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /aor/%e2%80%9d http://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair/
```

However, this does not work, when I input:

```
http://www.datanumen.com/aor/%e2%80%9d
```

in FireFox or IE, the browser still said the page not found(404) error.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

%E2%80%9D is the encoding for a quote mark: Your redirect is working fine, but the %E2%80%9D has already been encoded to a " by the time you see it.... so your code is redirecting to http://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair/%E2%80%9D

%E2%80%9D is the encoding for a right quotation mark, so the URL appears as http://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair/"

If you swap %E2%80%9D for " in your original code, it should work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `\x` escape and a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^aor/\xe2\x80\x9d http://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair/ [L,R=301]
```

Since `%E2%80%9D` is URL encoded, by the time the URL-file mapping processor gets to it, it's already been decoded so you need to match against the decoded characters.